# Write biSp in point-free form using as few terms as possible

Tags: restricted-source, atomic-code-golf, functional-programming, haskell, combinatory-logic

The Haskell function [`biSp`](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/concatenative/Control-Concatenative.html#v%3abiSp) has type signature

```
biSp :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> e
```

and (for those who prefer [combinator calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic)) can be defined as

```
biSp g h f x y = f (g x) (h y)
```

Your task is to implement `biSp` in point-free form (equivalently: as a combinator without any lambdas) using only two primitives:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

or

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
flip f x y = f y x
```

For those with a background in combinator calculus, these are respectively the [B and C combinators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinators_B.2C_C).

You may define helper functions so long as they are point-free. Your score is the total number of terms in all right-hand-side expressions.

#### Testing

You can test a Haskell solution without installing any software using Ideone. By providing an explicit type alongside the definition you ensure a compile-time error if the function is incorrect. E.g. using the `:pl` reference implementation ([online demo](http://ideone.com/QF379D)):

```
biSp :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> e
biSp = flip . ((flip . ((.) .)) .) . flip (.)
main = putStrLn "Compiled ok"
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what it is the above is doing (note that I'm not very familiar with functional programming).

Comment: I added a link.  Why so many close votes?  Is this not a good programming puzzle?

Comment: @dspyz the close-vote reason selected so far is "it's unclear what you're asking". so I guess that's the reason.

Comment: Even with the link, I'm still not sure what you want (possibly due to my lack of familiarity with functional languages). In general, language-specific tasks are looked down because not everyone can participate.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this could be written in any functional language.  But it lends itself more nicely to haskell.  I'll remove the haskell tag.  What's unclear about it?

Comment: This is indeed very language specific. But the question is certainly clear, for someone with minimal knowledge of Haskell (very minimal in my case).

Comment: Actually, I'm starting to wonder if an optimal solution could be found with some sort of BFS.  There's probably a lot of theory I don't know revolving around this sort of thing.

Comment: Looks like an interesting problem, but perhaps out of reach for those unfamiliar with haskell.  If possible, can you provide some examples of expected input and output?

Comment: I don't think the problem really lends itself to input and output.  However, I think anything which matches the type signature and compiles (not including recursive functions and calls to "error") is correct.  So, in that sense, you could say the input is the GHC compiler together with the type signature and the output is no compilation error

Comment: Edited to clarify for people who are familiar with combinator calculus but not Haskell, or who know other FP languages but don't want to try finding proper definitions of `flip` and `(.)`. I was tempted to delete the [tag:haskell] tag, but I wasn't sure why you had edited it back in after once editing it out. I don't think there's anything Haskell-specific about this other than the names of the functions: the type signature syntax is the same as SML, and the core question could be an exercise in *To Mock a Mockingbird*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 7 terms

We again define a helper combinator `BBQ = B B (C B)`, which has reduction rule

```
BBQ w x y z = x y (w z)
```

Then `biSp = BBQ BBQ BBQ`

```
  BBQ BBQ BBQ g h f x y
= BBQ g (BBQ h) f x y
= BBQ h f (g x) y
= f (g x) (h y)
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/O9JzKU)

By brute force, this is the only 7-term solution and there is no smaller solution.

#### 8 terms

There are a handful of 8-term solutions. Firstly, the obvious

```
C BBQ BBQ BBQ
```

which reduces in one step to `BBQ BBQ BBQ`.

Then there are three solutions of the form `X X X` with a five-term `X`:

- `X = B (B B) C B` which reduces in one step to `BBQ`
- `X = C B (C B) B` which reduces in one step to `BBQ` and allows the further extraction, for no net gain or loss, of a helper combinator `Q = C B`
- `X = C (B C (B B))`

There is one solution of the form `X X` with a six-term `X`:

- `X = C B (B B (C B))` (again, with an equivalent version which extracts `Q = C B`)

And there is one solution which can only be written in 8 terms with two helper combinators:

```
Q = C B
X = Q (Q Q B)
biSp = X X
```

Answer (score 3):

### 9 terms

Define a helper combinator `BBQ = B B (C B)`, which has reduction rule

```
BBQ w x y z = x y (w z)
```

Then we have three options:

1. `C (B B BBQ) BBQ`
2. `B (C B BBQ) BBQ`
3. `C (B (C BBQ) BBQ)`

To show the equivalence of the first two:

```
  C (B B BBQ) BBQ g h f x y
= B B BBQ g BBQ h f x y
= B (BBQ g) BBQ h f x y

  B (C B BBQ) BBQ g h f x y
= C B BBQ (BBQ g) h f x y
= B (BBQ g) BBQ h f x y
```

We can then continue:

```
= BBQ g (BBQ h) f x y
```

That then gives the equivalence with the third:

```
  C (B (C BBQ) BBQ) g h f x y
= B (C BBQ) BBQ h g f x y
= C BBQ (BBQ h) g f x y
= BBQ g (BBQ h) f x y
```

Finally

```
= BBQ h f (g x) y
= f (g x) (h y)
```

In Haskell this is (picking one of the options):

```
bbq = (.) (.) (flip (.))
biSp = flip ((.) (.) bbq) bbq
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/MRxl5V)

Answer (score 3):

### 9 terms

This uses an intermediate combinator which I shall call `Par` for *parity*, because of the way it groups its arguments. `Par = B C (B B)` has reduction rule

```
Par w x y z = (w y) (x z)
```

Then `biSp = C (B Par (C Par))`. To demonstrate:

```
  C (B Par (C Par)) g h f x y
= B Par (C Par) h g f x y
= Par (C Par h) g f x y
= C Par h f (g x) y
= Par f h (g x) y
= f (g x) (h y)
```

In Haskell this is

```
par = (.) flip ((.) (.))
biSp = flip ((.) par (flip par))
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/nVfNcx)

Answer (score 1):

### 10 terms

```
         1  2     3  4   5  6   7  8   9  10
biSp = flip . ((flip . ((.) .)) .) . flip (.)
```

Another reference solution, that from ghci-on-acid's `:pl` command.

Answer (score 0):

**10 terms**

```
        1   2    3   4   5    6   7   8
biSp = cf ((.) (cf ((.) (.))) . flip (.))

      9   10
cf = (.) flip
```

***Another 10 term solution***

```
        1   2  3  4  5  6 7  8
biSp = fc ((.) . fc) . fc . fc

       9  10
fc = flip (.)
```